# PHP: cURL: Running multiple queries on the same website

Tags: php, curl

I'm having a little difficulty in figuring out how to run multiple cURL requests, and I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong. It may be that my code for logging in via the webform that I've written is incorrect, but its difficult to test that on its own as I do need to run the first query before I can do that.

This is the code I have for my first query;

```
$handle = curl_init();

$login_user = 'user';
$login_pass = 'pass';

$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$postdata = "username=".$username."&password=".$password; 

curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://somewebsiteexample.php');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $login_user . ":" . $login_pass );
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);

curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($response);
?>
```

Which gets me past the basic http authentication. Now I need to be able to log in to the site by posting the request to the webform php page.

I've seen plenty of examples of how to do this, but only on their own, and not as a second cURL request.

I have all the information I need to be able to do each individual request, but I'm not sure how to combine the two requests together. Do I do it in the same cURL session?

I get the feeling that I do need to do seperate curl initialisation requests and that I need to store the login information from the first request via a cookie using CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR. (Or can I run my second query in the same curl_init()?)

If that is the case, how do I store the basic http authentication request so that when I next initialise curl, I am already logged into the website where I can then POST to the webform? I can probably figure out the rest once I know how to do multiple cURL requests.

I'm fairly new to cURL (I still use file_get_contents() for web pages a lot of the time), so I'm also a little unsure on which cURL options are absolutely necessary for logging in via webform. Some seem quite obvious, whereas others do not. This is something I can probably figure out on my own, but its hard to find a solid tutorial for logging in with cURL that has a breakdown of what each CURLOPT constant does in that particular context.

The php.net manual has a lot of information, and while it does tell you what the various cURL options relate to, it doesn't provide specific examples of their specific usages. If there is another resource site where I can get a more in-depth explanation of cURL, that would also be appreciated.

Comment: You can leave the handle open and make another request.

Comment: Worst case, just repeat the entire above code with different variables.

Comment: @deceze: That wouldn't work. The first request is a basic http authentication request, the second request is logging in by POSTING to a webform. It's not a simple copy/paste. I need to be logged in via the first request to even be able to access the page with the webform on.

Comment: @Jack: This is what I tried, however I think it failed because I wasn't storing my login information from my first request. I'm not sure, though.

Comment: Well, you can use `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` to see the request and response headers for debugging; it should also keep cookie data until it's closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look into ways curl is debugged. Curl naturally won't trace anything, you need to call for `curl_error($curl)` and `curl_errno($curl)` after the request, but before the resource is closed with `curl_close($curl)`.

You also need to trace `curl_getinfo($curl)` for details regarding request and response. Make sure your *blank page* is not caused by syntax errors in your script.

Next part. Add `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` for cookies handling. Do the second request on the same curl resource, run `curl_close($curl)` after all requests have been done. Curl saved most of the setup between requests, so don't worry about that.

I would also suggest adding user agent and referer settings to make your request look more natural.

Comment: My problems seems to be in running both requests in a single session. I'll try splitting them up. Firstly though I'll test the other part of my script on a website where I don't require basic http authentication, however I've gone over the code and I can't see what would be causing it to just return a blank page. I'll see if I can do some debugging as you suggest.

Comment: It appears that my problem may be that my cookie isn't storing my basic http authentication. Seperating them into two requests shows the "Authorization Required" page. Still no closer to figuring out what the problem is unfortunately.

Comment: Don't separate into two requests - it refreshes everything, no wonder you get "authorize again". Also, try addin the following parameters `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, FALSE);` and `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, FALSE);`.

Comment: Well the good news is that within my single request I can now POST data to my form, however it keeps telling me my username and password are incorrect, and I'm POSTing everything required by the page.

This bit does concern me a little;

javascript: document.authform.submit()

If that is what's preventing me making my POST request, then I'm probably stuck.

Comment: You are missing something. Maybe javascript alters the input fields before submit? Use some browser addon like HttpFox to see exact data submited by browser and compare it to the data submited by your script.

Comment: Good idea. if I can see exactly what's being POSTed I can hopefully find where the problem is.

Comment: Ah yes, it does appear that there is some hidden form data there that wasn't visible in the html of the source page; two variables that don't appear particularly vital but if the POST requires them that may explain it. I shall try the complete POST request later. Fingers crossed that does the trick.

Comment: Problem solved. After doing a little digging with HttpFox, and making my post data an associative array rather than a string, I am now able to log in. There may be a couple of other issues, but as far as my question is concerned it has been answered. Thanks Ranty. HttpFox was invaluable.

Comment: Indeed, I can't imagine my curl work without it. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

Logins are handled via cookies (assuming they're *not* handled via URL parameters). What you need to do is store the cookies received in the response to the login query and send the cookies back on each request. cURL can automate this for you if you use the `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` to *store* received cookies and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` to *load* cookies from for each request. Just set both options to the same file.

Comment: That makes sense. I think this is probably what I need to do. Would I still need to use CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE if I'm still in the same cURL initialisation?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. As far as I know a "curl handle" is just an API metaphor to keep the set options together. I don't know/think it handles any state between requests using it, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Yeah. Still having problems. Just getting a blank page returned now. So really no closer to figuring out what I'm doing wrong unless I just post my entire code.

Comment: At this point I'm just getting a blank page. I'm not getting any errors outputted to my window. I've gotten so confused by all the different options that at this point I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong. I'll see if I can post the code.